# What does "strip away all the sound and fury" means?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

I have seen this quotation from Ed Miliband's [current rhetoric](http://www.britishpoliticalspeech.org/speech-archive.htm?speech=355):

> "**Strip away all of the sound and fury** and what people across England, Scotland and Wales, across every part of the UK, are saying is that this country doesn't care about me," Miliband then says. "Politics doesn't listen. The economy doesn't work. And they're right. But this Labour party has a plan to put it right."

So what does it mean? I do know that "sound" could mean "calm and sane" and "fury" could mean "angry and violent", but how do they fit in here?

Comment: It's referencing [a quote from *MacBeth*](http://www.goodreads.com/work/quotes/1896522-the-tragedy-of-macbeth) and refers to the babbling of idiots. Draw your own conclusions.

Comment: @Robusto Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @Robusto but how come the "sound" here means  idiot?

Comment: _Life's but a walking shadow, a poor player
That struts and frets his hour upon the stage
And then is heard no more: it is a tale
Told by an idiot, full of sound and fury,
Signifying nothing._ Macbeth, scene V

Comment: @Vim 'sound and fury' together suggest all the activity of the idiot, lots of talking and gesturing. Robusto was saying that sound and fury is the babbling that idiots do, not that either is a synonym for idiot.

Comment: I miscapitalized Macbeth. Stupid fingers.

Comment: @Mitch   Not idiots but **actors**. And that applies to Ed's take on politics as much as those he castigates.

Comment: About the quote, I'm more concerned about the 'me' that 'This country doesn't care about me' is referring to, 'people across England' or Ed Miliband himself.

Comment: @Mitch it should refer to the people, since he later seemed to show his party's resolution to "get things right" for the people ( and not likely for himself).

Comment: @Mitch and everyone sorry, idiotic comment. Swept away by the whole quote, and Macbeth is the play you are not supposed to mention. It brings bad luck.

Comment: @Hugh What do you mean by saying it brings bad luck?

Comment: @Vim, Theatrical Superstition.  Wiki:- "Shakespeare's play Macbeth is said to be cursed, so actors avoid saying its name when in the theatre (the euphemism "The Scottish Play" is used instead). Actors also avoid even quoting the lines from Macbeth before performances, particularly the Witches' incantations."

Answer (score 2):

The quote is explaining the core meaning, if you take out all the drama and emotions, of what people are saying.

Answer (score 1):

In this case 'sound and fury' is meant to mean "angry polemics." (*Polemics* because he is implicitly complaining that the arguments are one-sided, and therefore merely noise.)